# Downloaded files in Angularjs doesn't saves properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, http, asp.net-web-api

My Web API method either returns the single file or zip file having multiple files. This is Web API implementation.

```html
        public HttpResponseMessage Download([FromUri] List<string> fileNames)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                if (fileNames.Count > 1)
                {
                    List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
                    
                    MemoryStream memoryStreamOfFile = new MemoryStream();

                    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                    {
                        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
                        {
                            zip.AddFile(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"\Uploaded\" + fileName);
                        }
                        zip.Save(memoryStreamOfFile);
                        memoryStreamOfFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        result.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStreamOfFile);
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "files.zip";
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                        return result;
                    }
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNames[0]))
                {
                    string filePath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"\Uploaded\" + fileNames[0];
                    
                    var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    return result;
                }
                return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not found.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
            }
        }
```

This method is working completely fine, I'm sure because when I request to this method through "Advanced Rest Client", a Google Chrome extension, file gets downloaded and works perfectly.

But when I request this method through Angularjs service call, file doesn't open. Image files give me following error

[image]

following for PDF

[image]

and following for zip

[image]

From [Advance Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) behavior is expected, but not with Angularjs.
Following is my Angular code

```js
"download": {
        method: "GET",
        url: "api/files/Download/",
        params: { fileNames: "@fileNames" },
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream"
        }
 }
```

```js
return fileManagerClientService.download({ fileNames: fileName })
                .$promise
                .then(function (data) {
                    
                    console.log(data);
                    appInfo.setInfo({ message: "files downloaded successfully" });

                    try {
                        var blob = new Blob([data]);

                        if (typeof (fileName) == "string")
                            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
                        else
                            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "AllFiles.zip");

                    } catch (ex) {
                        console.log(ex);
                    }
                },
```

Please tell me what I'm missing on the Angular side? I've tried many code snippets but they didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys, the issue is resolved by replacing $resource with $http call.
Here is the working code,

```js
function download(fileName) {
            appInfo.setInfo({ busy: true, message: "loading files" });
            

            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "api/files/Download/",
                params: { fileNames: fileName },
                responseType: "arraybuffer"
            }).then(function (data) {
                appInfo.setInfo({ message: "files downloaded successfully" });

                try {
                    var blob = new Blob([data.data]);

                    if (typeof (fileName) == "string")
                        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
                    else
                        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "AllFiles.zip");

                } catch (ex) {
                    console.log(ex);
                }
            }, function (error) {

            });
        }
```

This is working code, I hope someone would have a better solution using $resource and why it wasn't working with $resource anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent 2 days to understand why I download a corrupted file through the $resource.